# Sql in where Condition and number of Fetched Rows

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

Hello currenty i found my self in a dillema lets se if there is a solution to this:

Lets say we have a table Users with field User_id, Building_id

Table Values:

```
user_id | building_id
-------   -----------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 2
4       | 2
5       | 2
```

and we make a select

```
Select * from users where building_id = 1
```

this will fetch 2 lines.

```
Select * from users where building_id = 2
```

this will fetch 3 lines.

```
Select * from users 
  where (:modus = 1 and building_id = 1) or 
        (:modus = 2 and building_id = 2)
```

How much line will it fetch if i pass :modus = 1?? it reads 5 lines but show 2.

So the question is how do make sql with params that would not read all data and show only part of it?

### **Update 1 (Visual result):**

Result made in IBExpert:

Normal SQL

[image: Normal SQL]

[image: Result]

SQL with Parameter, passing Modus = 1

[image: SQL with Parameters]

[image: Result]

Visual result in both cases:

[image]

### **Update 2 (Real Database resul):**

Non parameter building = 1

[image]

Fetched as expected 12

[image]

Read as expected 12

[image]

---

Non Parameter Building = 2

[image]

fetched as expected 5924

[image]

Read as expected 5924

[image]

---

Parametirized where Param = 1 and therefore Building = 1

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the upper right Fetched amount ses 12

[image]

But in performance analysis its 5936

[image]

Comment: Could you define what you mean with fetches? Fetches from a SQL client API perspective are the rows retrieved from the server, with that definition if only 2 are shown, then only 2 have been fetched (unless the client does additional filtering of course); I don't think this is what you mean with fetches.

Comment: Dont know how to define that, we are yous IBExpert and it has a Performance Analysis and there it ses Indexed and Non-Indexed Reads

Comment: Your current query is working as you expect - maybe; the problem is that SQL 1) doesn't follow short-circuit logic, really, mostly because 2) just about every RDBMS has an optimizer, which looks for the "best" path to return the data.  Smart optimizers are _able_ (but **not** guaranteed) to essentially ignore the "always false" condition (ie, pass `1` into `:modus = 2`).  **You have no direct control over this**.  It sometimes works well for simple queries over small data sets; anything big, and you may as well use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i know that the SQL itself work correctly. But just trying to optimize it so it doesnt do thousands of read just to find 2 lines that need to be shown,regarding Dynamic SQL main problem is that we use procedures where you cannot change anything , or am i wrong?

Comment: For a simple query like this?  It'll _probably_ behave like you want, and give a good plan.   For something complicated, where the data in the table(s) isn't nicely distributed, and where there's lots of options?  Start rolling dice, sometimes ya' win, sometimes they come up snake eyes.  SQL Server has some fairly nasty caveats for this type of thing, apparently.  What do you mean you can't change things in procedures?  A lot of dynamic SQL is performed in user-defined procedures, usually.  Not that this query requires more than a replacement variable for `BUILDING_ID`, essentially.

Comment: i think im doing something wrong, lets say there are 5000 users with Building 1 and only 10 with building 2, if i do the sql with parameter passing this `where (:param = 1 and building_id=1) or (:param = 2 and building_id=2)` and passing :param = 2 how many reads should it do? 5000 or 10???

Answer (score 0):

When you use parametrized queries, the Firebird optimizer decides on the plan at preparation time, not at execution time.  Internally Firebird **does not know** that both parameters are the same (Firebird only has positional and not named parameters, the named parameters are emulated by the access component/driver you're using!). This means that Firebird prepares a plan that will evaluate both conditions and therefor it will perform all the reads for both.

I assume that your conditions are more complicated than in your question, so a solution like `building_id = :modus` or `building_id = CASE :modus WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 END` won't work.

You could try to `UNION` the two queries, it is possible that the query execution doesn't actually read the data pages for one of the two union streams if it finds the condition evaluates to false.